# Lua / Love 2d : Scale Image with pixels

Tags: image, lua, resize, scale, love2d

## Hello !

With Lua and Love 2d, I'd like to resize an image with pixels :

```
img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/bg.png")

-- resize the image (500 x 400)

function love.draw()

    love.graphics.draw(bg, 0, 0)

end
```

Comment: `love.graphics.draw(bg, 0, 0, 0, 500/img:getWidth(), 400/img:getHeight())`

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want to scale an image in pixelart style and you don't want this blurred effect, you can set the default filter to nearest before loading the images with love.graphics.newImage(path):

```
love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")
love.graphics.newImage(path)
love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("linear", "linear") --[[ If you want to let the filter like before ]]
```

I recommend you to visit love2d forums.
If this don't work, visit [this forum](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=80687)